# python application to manipulate data and show it on web

Tags: python, web

I want to create a python application that accepts an input from a web page and searching it in database and again return result to that web page. but I don't know where can I start?
Is Django useful in my case?
or maybe requests library? 
What are they for?

Comment: I'm sorry, mate, but this website is for more detailed and specific coding questions and your question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it in Django.

[What you need is a form to take the data input from a user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/)

[and then with a view you can turn the proper response you want.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the question is to broad. I will however try to answer the question in general terms. Yes, Django can be used to achieve this, but might be a bit overkill if that is the only purpose of the web application.

This can be done using flask and a mysql datbase. What you need is a form in HTML that posts to a function in python.

```
 <form action="/INSERTFUNCTIONNAME" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" attributeName="name" class="form-control" />
     </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

then define a function in python with the route "/INSERTFUNCTIONNAME"

```
@webserver.route('/INSERTFUNCTIONNAME')
def test_home():
    if 'name' in request.form:
          do logic
          then return view with results
          return send_from_directory('', 'index.html')
```